# Multiprocessing efficiency confusion

Tags: python

I'm running a Python job utilizing the Multiprocessing package and here's the issue. When I run with 3 processors on my dual-core hyper-threaded laptop I hit 100% CPU usage in each core no problem. I also have a workstation with 6 cores, hyper-threaded, and when I run the same script on that machine each core barely breaks 30%. Can someone explain why this is? I was thinking it was I/O but if that's the case then my laptop shouldn't be utilized 100%, right?

Code below with short explanation:
MultiprocessingPoolWithState is a custom class that fire up N_Workers workers and gives each of them a copy of a dataframe (so that the df isn't shipped over the wire to each worker for each operation). And tups is a list of tuples which are used as the slicing criteria for each operation that process_data() does.

Here's an example of the code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
config = dict()
N_Workers = mp.cpu_count-1
def process_data(tup):
    global config
    df = config['df']
    id1 = tup[0]
    id2 = tup[1]
    df_want = df.loc[(df.col1 == id1) & (df.col2 == id2)]
    """ DO STUFF """
    return series_i_want

pool = MultiprocessingPoolWithState(n=N_Workers, state=df)
results = pool.map(process_data,tups)
```

I'm not sure what other details anyone would need so I'll add what I can (I can't give the custom class as it's not mine but a co-worker's). The main thing is that my laptop maxes out cpu usage but my workstation doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried running with the cores over-subscribed? For instance, what happens if you run with 12 processes on your 6 core machine? Does that bring up your utilization? More importantly, does that decrease net run-time?

Comment: If your laptop have SSD disks and the other machinne has physical spinning disks, that could account for differences of this order - where the mechanical disk machine will be bottlenecked by serialization operations that hit the filesystem. The workaround should simply be to spawn more workers.

Comment: @Richard I have spun up 11 processes since it's hyper-threaded, are you suggesting I fire up 24 processes or something?

jsbueno I'm unsure of the architecture of either machine actually but I can explore that with our IT team.

Comment: @jsbueno It looks like they're both SSD

Comment: @NicPayne: Yes, I'm suggesting your try spinning up more processes than you think you need.

Comment: @NicPayne: Another hypothesis is that your process is not compute-bound. If you're doing a lot of disk/network activity in your worker processes, you shouldn't expect full CPU utilization.

Comment: @Richard There's no network activity going on during the steps where multiprocessing is being used. I will try to fire up 24 workers and see what happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For those who might be curious here I think I've figured it out (although this answer won't be highly technical). Within the """ DO STUFF """ I call statsmodels.x13.x13_arima_analysis() which is a Python wrapper for X13-Arima-SEATS which is a sales adjustment program the US Census Bureau creates for seasonally adjusting time series (like sales records). I only had one copy of the x13.exe that the wrapper calls so on my laptop (Windows 10) I think the OS created copies of the .exe automatically for each process however on our Server (Windows Server 2012 R2) each process was waiting in line for its own chance at using the .exe - so on our server I had an I/O issue that my laptop handled automatically. The solution was simple - create a .exe with a unique path for each process to utilize and boom the program is 300 times faster than before.

I do not understand how the different OS's handled the issue with multiple processes looking at the same .exe but that's my theory which seemed to be confirmed when adding the process-dependent paths.